# Really simple FOSS CSS for a report?

Tags: html, css, template

I'm creating a web-based report. It will be a single column, no menu. Just titles, graphs, tables. Maybe a header and a footer.

I've scoured the internet for a free, open source (or just 'free') CSS 'template' that will turn my grotty looking HTML page in to a nicely colored page with good fonts. Something simple I can just drop  in.

Is there such a thing? My issue is that I'm not a designer, I just want to pop something in and have it work and look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to just drop something in and not think about it, the [Blueprint CSS modules](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/) give a pretty decent, if plain, result. All you'll really have to do is some minor layout work to make the content column whatever size you want, as slapping it into a 960px one will be too wide for comfortable reading.

Blueprint is probably the most well-known, but [Atatonic](http://atatonic.timbenniks.nl/) and [Baseline](http://baselinecss.com/typography.html) are also worth considering.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for, I knew something like these must exist but it's quite difficult to wade through a search for 'free css template'.